# How to delete/remove screen/page from the display in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I have one `Loader` using which I am loading the multiple screen/pages.

I have around 10 QML screen/pages which I am loading in the loader one by one on mouse events.

On some of the screens I need to set transparency using `QWidget::setMask()` function to make some part of the screen/page make transparent and Punch hole the screen.

I am doing set mask from CPP code using `QWidget::setMask()` on the `rootObject`, which is `Loader` screen.

`QWidget::setMask` is working perfectly, but masked area displays previously loaded screen/page.

So I have the question, Is `Loader` element properly deletes/removes the loaded component from the display before loading the new screen/page in the `Loader`, as mentioned in documents http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-loader.html.

Also there are two function named `Component.onDestroyed` and `Component.onDestruction`

When I load new screen/page in the Loader `onDestruction` event is getting fired for the Loaded screen.

I want to completely remove/destroy the screen/page from the display once we load new page in the loader.
I have also tried to set the visibility and opacity of the previously loaded screen, but still I am able to see the Previously loaded screen/page in the masked area.

If I set loader's `source = ""` and `sourceComponent = undefined` then also I can see the previous loaded page in Loader, it is not refreshing the screen. The previous page is destroyed but it is not cleared/removed from the display.

What should be the reason?

Comment: just to clarify: you are using one single Loader and change its source-property to one of your 10 screens?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you manage to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `QWidget::clearMask()` function in C++ when receiving signal `Component.onDestruction` in loaded qml file or when receiving `onSourceChanged` in `Loader`?